# Logcat Android what does this line mean

Tags: android, logcat

what does this line mean?  FBI

07-02 19:58:00.229 26739 26739 E **FBI** : Can't load library: dlopen failed: library "libmagtsync.so" not found

### Bootstrap Error

Termux can only be run as the primary user.

Bootstrap binaries compiled for Termux have hardcoded $PREFIX path and cannot be installed under any path other than `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr`.

### Termux Files Info

**TERMUX_REQUIRED_FILES_DIR_PATH ($PREFIX)**: `/data/data/com.termux/files`

**ANDROID_ASSIGNED_FILES_DIR_PATH**: `/data/user/10/com.termux/files`

Comment: Did you figure out? I've the same error and qs. What does FBI stand for here?